# Multi-page document scanning

Tags: java, linux, pdf, inputstream, scanning

I'm making a java program that scans document and saves it to pdf. It works like a charm for a single page document. I run bash command from java, create BufferedImage from InputStream and then build pdf document using itext.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scanimage --resolution=300 --format png --device-name " + device.getName());
BufferedImage bI = ImageIO.read(p.getInputStream());
```

The trouble begins when trying to scan multi-page document (batch scanning). Namely, I don't know what to do with resulting InputStream.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scanimage --batch --resolution=300 --format png --device-name " + device.getName());
```

I see a possible workaround, saving images to temporary files and then building pdf document using these files. However, I would like to avoid that. Is there a way to acquire array of BufferedImage from InputStream given by scanimage?

Comment: Isn't scanimage --batch writing the output to a bunch of files anyway? So you can't really do anything with it...

Comment: So the returned InputStream is unusable?